# Points behind lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to make a graph of the two minimums of a function, however I ran into some     trouble
[image: a plot]

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "plot.png"
f(x) = x**4-25*x**2+20*x
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-300:600]
set label 1 "" at -3.7207,f(-3.7207) point pt 7 lt 1
set label 2 "" at 3.3154,f(3.3154) point pt 7 lt 2
plot f(x) title "x^4+25x^2+20x"
```

As you can see on the green point, it's behind the curve, I would like to make it so the green point is in front.

I found a workaround by using multiplot to plot the points after the curve, but it seems absurd to me that you have to use this workaround.

[image: another plot]

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "plot1.png"
f(x) = x**4-25*x**2+20*x
set multiplot
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-300:600]
plot f(x) title "x^4+25x^2+20x"
set label 1 "" at -3.7207,f(-3.7207) point pt 7 lt 1
set label 2 "" at 3.3154,f(3.3154) point pt 7 lt 2
plot NaN notitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clippy says: it looks like you want the `front` keyword. From the gnuplot docs:

> If `front` is given, the label is written on top of the graphed data.
>   If  `back` is given (the default), the label is written underneath the
>   graphed  data.  Using `front` will prevent a label from being obscured
>   by dense data.

Try

```
set label ... front
```